# What is preventing usage of KEYCODE_POWER and KEYCODE_SLEEP

Tags: java, android, permissions, key

I am working on a remote controller for Android TV. 
I replaced the user keyboard (Leanback Keyboard) with a modified one so when it is selected I can send network commands to use several functions.

For example, KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT works to make dpad left move.

However, for turning on/off I need following keycodes to work:
KEYCODE_SLEEP
KEYCODE_POWER
KEYCODE_WAKEUP

But these don't work.

I use the following code for sending keycodes:

```
            InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
                ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SLEEP));
                ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SLEEP));
```

but this does not work.
I doubted about permissions, so I added DEVICE_POWER permission but it did not help. what is missing ?